# Putty Dynamic Title (with $PWD)

Tags: dynamic, window, title, putty

I would like putty terminal to display the current folder. Is this possible ?

For example, when i'm in `$HOME`, the putty window title would be `$HOME`.

Then, if I do `cd $HOME/foodir`, the title would change to `$HOME/foodir`.

Is that possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Setting PS1 did not work for me (putty 0.62).

I'm using bash, and here's what works :

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\033\\" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"'
```

Comment: To make this work as intended, I had to add a backslash before the tilde in the PWD expansion.

Answer (score 2):

Putty window is like a terminal on Linux, so it´s behavior is like a window in x mode on linux for example, so...

U can use the environment variable PS1 to define the title, like in this post: http://www.networkinghowtos.com/howto/how-to-set-the-putty-window-title-via-script/

In my case I defined the PS1 variable in /home/user/.bash_profile:

```
PS1="\[\e]2;\u@\H\w\a\[\e[32;1m\]>\[\e[0m\]"
```

But that´s my configuration, U can create your own.

...