# $PWD in window title bar, both in Bash and Tmux

Tags: bash, tmux, pwd

I want my window title bar to show my PWD.  In my `.bashrc` I have this which seems to do the trick for Bash:

```sh
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

However, when I use Tmux, the window shows the directory of wherever I launched Tmux, not the current directory I've navigated to within Tmux.

Below, I launched Tmux in `~`, then navigate to `~/Downloads`.  The title bar still shows `~`.  Behind it is a window where I navigate to `~/Downloads` using just Bash; it shows what I want:
[image]

Here are things I already tried that did not work:

- [Putty Dynamic Title (with $PWD)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19050611/putty-dynamic-title-with-pwd)
- https://superuser.com/questions/249293/rename-tmux-window-name-to-prompt-command-ps1-or-remote-ssh-hostname

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess when I tried this before it was in combination with some other changes... now it works:

in `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g set-titles on
set -g set-titles-string '#T'
```

in `~/.bashrc` (by the way I added `|screen` to the switch statment):

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='> '
    #PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*|screen)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```